# Apple GameCenter scoring

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

It seems to me that GC doesn't override scores that are less then the current one. This is quite a problem because how do I suppose to override leader boards that store parameters like fire accuracy (say 56%, 66% and so on) ? I also can't find any way to reset the score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That dependes on how do you have it in iTunes Connect.

In iTunes Connect you can choose witch type of leaderboard you want, low to high, high to low. And every value is send to Game Center, they just wont save the better score.

The better score will be the bigger on low to high, and will be the lowest on hight to low.

About reseting the leaderboard you cant do that. Apple gives you 25 leaderboards, and thats all. You can only reset the archievements.

the work arround you can do is create a new leaderboard, rename the old to `Archives`, and rename the new to the name you want, but wen you reach yours 25 leaderboards cap you cant do nothing more.